# Chat schema with one side deletion

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, schema, chat

I'm struggling with a chat schema that permits deletion from one side of the conversation in a relational database (PostgreSQL).

Here is my best approach: [my schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvX7V.png)

All schemas I found were about deletion for both sides, and this is not what I need.
I want to be able to delete from one side of the conversation, **and if the conversation restarts, user 1 still has all messages and user 2 only those which was sent after the deletion**.
So my idea is to have many to many relational table(deleted_messages) that relates the messages with users, and full fill that table when a user deletes a conversation with those messages that were in that conversation.

However, I'm not sure if this approach is the best one because my database will need to see if the message wasn't deleted for every message that is retrieved. This will be messier and messier as the deleted_messages table grows and I worried about the performance.

There is any better solution for my problem, or this approach is good?
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned "if the conversation restarts, user 1 still has all messages and user 2 only those what was sent after the deletion". This come up to 2 scenarios:

1. If user deletes specific message, then you should go with the schema of what you already have.
2. If user deletes chat history which is point of time reference, then you should create separate table as written below. Having one record for each message in deleted message for single user will cause serious performance issues as the data grows.
   Create below table and filter the data based on timestamp while you fetch the data.

   create table deleted_chat_history
   (
   userId int,
   chatRoomId int,
   [timestamp] timestamp,
   foreign key (userId) references user,
   foreign key (chatRoomId) references chat_room
   )

Comment: I would not create another table at all, Instead add a column indicate the message is deleted (called a logical delete) then create a view that eliminates those messages. Actual removal of messages would be done during standard message archival processing. The advantage is less maintenance as you have just the 1 table, And easily reversible if needed,

Comment: @Blayer You cannot just as a flag like is_deleted in this condition because this messages is not deleted for all. Remember a chartroom can have multiple users, let's say for example 10 users and out of which 3 has deleted message history at different point of time, it would not work with what you suggest.

Comment: @Blayer Also, updating let's say 100000 rows let's say a conversation have in chat history by is_deleted flat to 1/true would be more performance concern than just inserting 1 row and select with a join. Also reversible process is easier this way as you don't have to toggle the flag for 1000s of messages, you can just delete a row from the new table.

Comment: In that case you have a m:m so you flag the resolution table.

Comment: @Belayer what do you mean by resolution table? Can you name it from the schema link mentioned above.

Comment: The m:m is what I have now and that will flag deleted messages in order of users but this is a bad design.
What @SUMITPATRO suggested is a better approach as we can save a lot of rows if we join messages with timestamps.
I will wait, maybe someone has an even better idea.